# Different SUID on different classes

Tags: serialization, deserialization, java, suid

Assuming that I have got completely different classes with different class names. Should I use different `serialVersionUID` in the classes?

If so, why is it necessary?

How does the JRE the deserialization exactly?

Comment: It doesn't matter for classes in different packages or with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no you don't need different SUID (all classes can use 1 for it)

when an object is serialized the class identifier (package.name.ClassName) and SUID are both part of the header to identify the class the object belongs to and to ensure that there is no incompatibility between the writing side and the reading side

but when you change a class structurally (add/remove a field) you should set a new SUID for that class (during debugging you can let the JVM create a new one at runtime based on the .class file)

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick answer. Do you know, how the serialization/deserialization is done by the JRE?
Wouldn't it be more useful to set the SUIDs to 1L by default? I don't understand the sense of the generated SUIDs.

Comment: remember to accept the answer you like best ;P and essentially the serializer writes the header then serializes each field, (it can handle loops with a caching system) also the generated SUIDs are based on a hash of the .class so that when it is changed the SUID is likely different from before

Comment: OK, cool, thanks for the explanation.

My problem with the generated SUID is: Why should i generate a SUID, if I can increment the SUID also? It is the same time exposure and more logical ;-)

Comment: @tmaier you could also forget to do the increment, but lets not get into that argument here

Comment: @tmaier The last paragraph of this answer is poor advice. You should aim *never* to change the SUID. There is a high degree of binary compatibility when objects are versioned, and you should be aiming never to disturb that. See the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.